# In Android Compose, how do I make button align to the bottom of the screen, but still remain at the bottom of scrollable content?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I have my content in a scrollable Column. I want to put some buttons at the bottom of the screen if there is not enough content to scroll, while being at the bottom of the scrollable content. I've been trying Spacers and weights, but nothing seems to be working.

This is my test code.

```
@Composable
fun TestScrollableContentWithButton() {
    var numItems by remember { mutableStateOf(20) }
    Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        ScrollableContent(numItems = numItems)
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            Button(onClick = { numItems++ }) { Text("Add Item") }
            Button(onClick = { numItems = 0 }) { Text("Clear Items") }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScrollableContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, numItems: Int) {
    repeat(numItems) {
        Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp), text = "Test Text $it")
    }
}
```

And here are some sample images showing how the code behaves. In the first image, the red outline is what I want to happen. The buttons should stick to the bottom of the screen if there is not enough content to scroll. The second image shows that the buttons are visible if the user has scrolled all the way to the bottom.
[image]

EDIT: For clarity, this is a 3rd image showing that the buttons are not visible until the user is scrolled all the way to the bottom.

[image]

The second and third images are the correct and current behavior of the code. Only the first image contains what I want to happen.

I remade this in regular xml to show what I want.
https://i.imgur.com/k30A4mj.mp4
This shows the buttons sticking to the bottom when there is not enough content to scroll, and getting pushed down to the bottom of the scrollable content if there is enough content to scroll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Updated answer:

Got it, the buttons should not be visible when there are a lot of items. Then I think you can just simply use a `Space` that will fill up the available space between the items and buttons. I tried it and it works for me. :)

```
@Composable
fun TestScrollableContentWithButton() {
    var numItems by remember { mutableStateOf(20) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()  // Add fill max size
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        ScrollableContent(numItems = numItems)

        // Spacer to fill up the available space
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            Button(onClick = { numItems++ }) { Text("Add Item") }
            Button(onClick = { numItems = 0 }) { Text("Clear Items") }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScrollableContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, numItems: Int) {
    repeat(numItems) {
        Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp), text = "Test Text $it")
    }
}
```

### Original answer - not valid:

I don't think you need to put the button's container into the scrollable content as it is always positioned at the bottom :)

We can solve it but putting only the text items into the scrollable column and having a regular parent column which would include the button's container as well. Hope it makes sense.

Below is the code that should be working. I separated the Composables, so they are reusable and more readable, but will leave it up to you. :)

```
@Composable
private fun ExampleContent() {
    var numItems by remember { mutableStateOf(20) }

    // This could also be box, if you want the content to scroll behind the buttons
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        // Weight is essential here so the scrollable content is filling all the available space
        ScrollableContent(
            numItems = numItems,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        )

        ButtonsContainer(
            onAddClicked = { numItems++ },
            onClearItemsClicked = { numItems = 0 },
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ButtonsContainer(
    onAddClicked: () -> Unit,
    onClearItemsClicked: () -> Unit,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
        Button(onClick = onAddClicked) {
            Text("Add Item")
        }

        Button(onClick = onClearItemsClicked) {
            Text("Clear Items")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ScrollableContent(
    numItems: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
    ) {
        repeat(numItems) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp),
                text = "Test Text $it",
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have made it more clear. I want the buttons to be part of the scrollable content so that the the user must scroll to the very bottom to see them. If there are 100 items and the user is scrolled all the way to the top, the buttons should not be visible.

Comment: Please refer to the updated answer. I am fairly new to Stackoverflow, probably need to find best practices on how to edit my answers for the future :)

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. fillMaxSize() did the trick!